# SOLR query negative number

Tags: jquery, solr

What is the correct way to query for negative totalsavings (see below for an example of what a *:* returns if you view enough))?  The ideal would be totalsavings:<0 but I don't think you can do that.

I tried totalsavings:-* and that gave an error.  I tried totalsavings:-* which also did not work.

I tried a regular expression which the documentation says should be between slashes:  totalsavings:/-.*/ but that did also not work.

I am stymied.

```
   "totalsavings": [
          -2031.42
        ],
```

Comment: have you tried to use quotes totalsavings:"-2031.42" ?

Comment: which field type you're using for totlasavings? please show schema.xml

Comment: Thankls: Type
tdouble

Answer (score 2):

Use an interval query, unless this is a string / text field (if it is, you should probably change it to get sorting etc. working as you'd expect):

```
totalsavings:[* TO 0}
```

This will return any values below zero. (`[` is interval inclusive, `}` is interval excluded from, so `[* TO 0]` would include those that are zero as well).

Comment: Is there a way to tell the data type of a field?  I am (originally) using the WEB interface.  After I test out the queries, they move to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape `-,` and so:

```
\-.*
```

Comment: Hi.  I did and put it in the text above.  Unfortunately, somehow the backslash got removed above and did not show.  Or else was replaced by a :.  But it did not work.